# Rubyで指数不等式を解く

Tags: ruby

AtCoder の以下の問題 ([ABC248-B](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc248/tasks/abc248_b)) について、ループを回して不等式を満たす最小の整数 `i` を求めることでACになりました。

> a*k^n≧bを満たす最小の非負整数nを求めよ。(a,b,kは自然数。k≧2)

それとは別に、直接、上の不等式を解くという方法も考えられます。
それでやってみたのが以下のコードなのですが、一つだけWAになりました。原因がわかりません。

```
a,b,k=gets.chomp.split(" ").to_a.map(&:to_i)
puts Math::log((b/a.to_f),k).ceil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AtCoderのテストケースは以下の場所で公開されています。
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nx3tnilzqz7df8a/AAAYlTq2tiEHl5hsESw6-yfLa?dl=0

WAになるテストケースを見てみると、以下のような入力となっています。

```
1 536870912 2
```

こちらの正しい出力は`29`ですが、ご提示のコードだと`30`が出力されます。

計算過程を追ってみると、`Math::log((b/a.to_f),k)`の結果が間違っていることが分かります。
`536870912`が`2 ** 29`なので、`Math::log(536870912.0,2)` = `29.0`となるべきなのに、実際に計算してみると誤差が入って`29.000000000000004`になってしまいます。こちらを切り上げて、`30`という誤った結果となっています。

浮動小数点数は誤差が入る可能性があるため、誤差が許容できない状況で使うのは避けるべきです。
特に、競技プログラムでは、このような誤差は狙い撃ちされます。
ケース名が「04_hack_log_01.txt」となっていることからも、`log`を使うとWAになるようにあえて追加されたテストケースであることは明白です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
誤差が原因ではないかとは思ってはいたのですが、意図的に誤差が生じるテストケースが作られているんですね。
それから、テストケースが公開されているとも知りませんでした。ご教示ありがとうございます。